# How to store privately a large data volume in Android?

Tags: android, storage, privacy, android-external-storage, internal-storage

The question is how can I store a big amount of data (several hundreds of Mb and more) and simultaneously keep it available only for my application?

Internal storage as I found out is limited and its size depends on device model. Could it be sufficient for large data volume storage? Could I store 500Mb and more in internal storage?

The alternative is to use external storage. As I know, external storage doesn't limit an application and it can use the whole external storage. However, data become available for user and other applications and it is unacceptable in my case. Is there a way to make data, which stores in external storage, private as if it stores in internal one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Internal storage as I found out is limited and its size depends on device model

Only on Android 1.x/2.x. On the *vast* majority of Android 3.0+ devices, internal and external storage are on the same partition and therefore have the same amount of space.

> Could I store 500Mb and more in internal storage?

On Android 3.0+, probably. The user may not have 500MB free, but that's not a limitation of internal storage, but just a limitation of "storage" in general.

> Is there a way to make data, which stores in external storage, private as if it stores in internal one?

Not really. You cannot prevent the user or other apps from deleting those files, for example. You can use Facebook's Conceal library to encrypt the files on external storage, with a generated encryption key stored on internal storage, to prevent users or other apps from changing the contents of the files (other than by simply corrupting them). However, again, this would only be relevant if you are still supporting Android 1.x/2.x; on Android 3.0+, just use internal storage.

Answer (score 0):

considering the constrains you up you really up with two possible approaches.

- use the internal storage but make sure to keep check on free memory and whenever the device can't handle it's a matter of letting your users know their device can't run your app.
- use the external memory and build a nice encryption on it so even if someone else get the files, the actual data on them will be meaningless without the proper decryption mechanism.

which option to choose is a product decision.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getExternalFilesDir()` to restrict the media store content provider from reading your app specific files from an external storage. But I think any other application with the same permission of `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` can access the files. Only way is to use the internal memory.

Im not sure what type of files you wish to store. If the files are less in number you can give a thought of using database, although this shall violate ACID principle. Alternatively you can think about restricting by using content providers.